# Smart pointers in a factory constructor seem to force the created object to know how it's being used

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I am using a factory to create some objects at runtime based on some user selections.

So I have something like this currently:

```
class UpdateServiceFactory{
  public:
    std::unique_ptr<UpdateService> create(Widget widget){
       if(widget.name == "name one"){
          auto dependency = std::make_unique<ChildDependency>();
          return std::make_unique<ChildUpdateService>(std::move(dep));
       }
  }
}
```

My ChildUpdateService can:

a) take a unique pointer to its `dependency`. On one hand, this seems ideal, because I want my `dependency` to go out of scope when my UpdateService is destroyed. But on the other hand, I am now forcing a lifetime policy on the *creator* of the object from an object that shouldn't really care about it, just for the sake of easy cleanup of the memory. For example, my `ChildUpdateService` has no idea if the factory wants to pass the same dependency it just created to another class as well, which a unique pointer would make impossible. And it seems I've now dictated that by specifying the smart pointer on my constructor.

b) I could take a raw `dependency` pointer into the constructor of the ChildUpdateService and pass it using unique_ptr::get. But now I have the issue of needing to manage the lifetime of the `dependency` pointer elsewhere. Something has to own it otherwise it's going to go out of scope as soon as the create function returns. At this point, the only object that knows about the pointer is my factory, but the factory shouldn't really be responsible for managing the pointer's lifetime either. Its job is to create the object and that's it. I feel like doing any more would be a violation of the SRP.

So my question is two fold, I suppose. 1) If a constructor takes a unique pointer, am I dictating a lifetime policy on the creator of the object that I shouldn't be? And 2) is there a pattern that solves this problem which I could (should) use, such as creating an intermediate object, whose job is to manage the lifetime of the dependency?

Comment: Why you selected `unique_ptr` to argument of `ChildUpdateService::ctor`?
Isn't it because `ChildUpdateService` should be the sole owner of the `dependency`?
If not, the choice to use `unique_ptr` is itself wrong.

Comment: @fana theoretically yes, but my question comes from that fact that the only reason I *know* it should be the sole owner is because I know *how* ChildUpdateService is being used. The service will be passed to a Page and when that page is destroyed the service should be destroyed also, as well as the dependency. But should the service really be dictating ownership based on how it's being used? It seems to me like a class having that knowledge is backwards. What if some other caller used the service in a different way and wanted the dependency to outlive the service?

Comment: If someone may have to let only the dependency to outlive, and if you want to provide an implementation that allows such usage, the usage you mentioned above with "I know..." is just one case.

Comment: Must service really be owner of dependency?
If service's works needs dependency, the simple form that the service's method requires a dependency as it's argument may be considerable. In this form, the factory creates and returns a pair of service and dependency. Caller can handle the lifetime of the service and of the dependency respectively.

Comment: Or... use shared_ptr<dependency> instead of unique_ptr<dependency>, And provide a way for the caller to get this shared_ptr.
This case, service is a owner of dependency, and caller can become a owner too, if wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Service type to decide this, then you require its assistance when creating the Dependency. You could do it like this:

```
class ServiceBase { // you need this anyway
  public:
    virtual ~ServiceBase() {}
};
class ChildUpdateService : public ServiceBase {
  private:
    // now, the class itself defines that it wants to store a unique_ptr.
    // not the generic factory!
    ChildUpdateService(std::unique_ptr<ChildDependency>);
  public:
    template <typename Dep, typename... Args>
    static std::unique_ptr<ChildUpdateService> make(Args&&... args) {
      return std::make_unique<ChildUpdateService>(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
};
```

If you have several Services like this, maybe create an intermediary class template  that employs CRTP.

This means that your generic factory doesn't have to decide how the respective Service implementation keeps its dependency around (as unique_ptr, as shared_ptr, as automatic member, etc.).

```
class UpdateServiceFactory {
  public:
    std::unique_ptr<UpdateService> create(Widget widget) {
      if (widget.name == "name one")
        return ChildUpdateService::make<ChildDependency>();
    }
}
```